# Update the DB value associated with an <input> element when its value changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to make something like this http://jsfiddle.net/4e756/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=text]').keyup(function(){
       var c=0;
       var a=$(this).attr('name'); //a is string
        //if var a change..a=a(old)+a(new) and c++; than i will
        //explode string and use it for ajax POST
    });
});
```

Every time that `var a` changes I want to use its value to increment some another variable. This will allow me to save the name of every `<input>` which changes.

Comment: Are you trying to preserve the original values of input fields? Why not just use a hidden input?

Comment: nah i need all inputs..but for every changed inputs value want to use attr('name') to send like POST with ajax and add changes in database

Comment: @Deathmras Also see my comment about using [$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to auto-convert from JS object to query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/4e756/2/)

Create a map outside of the scope of your [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change) handler. This handler will be fired only after all changes to the field are complete, not on every keyup. This will allow to you store the name and the updated value of all of the fields which change. You can then POST that to your server, or process it and POST only a subset if that's required.

Because it is a map, keys are unique. This means that if you change a field more than once it will still appear in the map only once, with its latest value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var changedFields = {};

    $('input[type=text]').change(function(){
       changedFields[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use [jQuery post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to send the data, using `$.post(url, data, successFunction);`. If your server accepts a query string of key-value pairs rather than JSON you will need to process the map into that first.

Comment: To auto convert your `changedFields` object to a query-string, use [`jQuery.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/). Usage: `$.param({"foo": "bar"})` > `foo=bar`. And here's an [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4e756/4/) of how to do the POST with jQuery. Note it's using JSON instead of a query string because that's what they support.

Comment: sry because i didn't see this...thats all what i need :) tnx u all

Answer (score 3):

Make the `a` variable global and add to it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var a=''; // initialize it as global and an empty string
$('input[type=text]').click(function(){
   var c=0;
  a = a + $(this).attr('name'); //a is string
    //if var a change..a=a(old)+a(new) and c++; than i will
    //explode string and use it for ajax POST
});
});
```

Comment: No, you seem to be `listening` only to when the user `click` into the field.

Comment: If you dont want duplicates, concatenate the strings with a delimiter, i.e. '^' so it would read a = a + '^' + $(this).attr('name'); and then you can split the string on the '^' character. After doing this, you can iterate the array and remove duplicate values. Or, before you concatenate the name, iterate the string and check to see if any sections of 'a' are equal to $( this ).attr('name'); and if they are, dont add the name.